# Delete empty values from form's params before submitting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some javascript which catches changes to a form then calls the form's regular submit function.  The form is a GET form (for a search) and i have lots of empty attributes come through in the params.  What i'd like to do is to delete any empty attributes before submitting, to get a cleaner url:  for example, if someone changes the 'subject' select to 'english' i want their search url to be

```
http://localhost:3000/quizzes?subject=English
```

rather than

```
http://localhost:3000/quizzes?term=&subject=English&topic=&age_group_id=&difficulty_id=&made_by=&order=&style=
```

as it is at the moment.  This is just purely for the purpose of having a cleaner and more meaningful url to link to and for people's bookmarks etc.  So, what i need is something along these lines, but this isn't right as i'm not editing the actual form but a js object made from the form's params:

```
  quizSearchForm = jQuery("#searchForm");
  formParams = quizSearchForm.serializeArray();
  //remove any empty fields from the form params before submitting, for a cleaner url
  //this won't work as we're not changing the form, just an object made from it.
  for (i in formParams) {
    if (formParams[i] === null || formParams[i] === "") {
      delete formParams[i];
    }
  }
  //submit the form
```

I think i'm close with this, but i'm missing the step of how to edit the actual form's attributes rather than make another object and edit that.

grateful for any advice - max

EDIT - SOLVED - thanks to the many people who posted about this.  Here's what i have, which seems to work perfectly.

```
function submitSearchForm(){
  quizSearchForm = jQuery("#searchForm");
  //disable empty fields so they don't clutter up the url
  quizSearchForm.find(':input[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);
  quizSearchForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Can I just say, it's very cool your thinking of your users like that.

Comment: Good question and nice answers: I have a big search form and most of the time only one field gets filled. Now the URLs are much shorter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The inputs with attribute `disabled` set to `true` won't be submitted with the form. So in one jQuery line:

```
$(':input[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Then why not just: $(':input[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: @Marko Dumic - `attr` will only act on the *first* item in the resulting collection.

Comment: @Marko - my bad, that applies to getting attributes, i.e. `.attr("foo")`

Comment: If you also want the unchecked checkboxes (which had the value 0) use this: `.find(':input').filter('[value=""],:checkbox[checked=false]').attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: Using the `disabled` attribute will usually change the appearance of the inputs if you have styles for `input[disabled]`. If you remove the `name` of the element it will have the same effect since only inputs with names are submitted:

`$(':input[value=""]').attr('name', '');`

Comment: Not fully working, you forgot the case where value is not defined, you must use also "$(':input:not([value])')" selector.

Comment: _Another problem_: Inputs populated by user don't get submitted. This is because the actual `value` HTML attribute is not populated on user input (at least in latest Chrome...), so if this attribute was empty on page load, `':input[value=""]'` returns true in all cases, even if a value was entered by the user.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working (anymore). Pretty annoying that this is the top answer. Working answer for me is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2418039/4883195

Answer (score 21):

```
$('form#searchForm').submit(function() {
    $(':input', this).each(function() {
        this.disabled = !($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This works for me better, because it takes into account new edited value in focused input field when I press Enter.

Comment: This is the right answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418022/431698 does not take the new edited value into account.

Comment: Small improvement: do ```this.disabled = this.disabled || this.value;``` to avoid accidentally enabling otherwise disabled inputs. Cost me half an hour...

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it that way if you call the form's `submit` method; that will submit the entire form, not the array you've had jQuery create for you.

What you can do is disable the form fields that are empty prior to submitting the form; disabled fields are omitted from form submission. So walk through the form's elements and for each one that's empty, disable it, and then call the `submit` method on the form. (If its target is another window, you'll then want to go back and re-enable the fields. If its target is the current window, it doesn't matter, the page will be replaced anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Well one thing you could do would be to disable the empty inputs *before* calling "serializeArray"

```
$('#searchForm').find('input, textarea, select').each(function(_, inp) {
  if ($(inp).val() === '' || $(inp).val() === null)
    inp.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

The "serializeArray()" routine will not include those in its results.  Now, you may need to go back and re-enable those if the form post is not going to result in a completely refreshed page.

Comment: If he's calling the form's own `submit` method, he doesn't need to call `serializeArray` at all.

Comment: Yes that's true, but the code sample cuts off, and he did after all call serializeArray in the first place. It'll work to disable the fields on a normal submit too, as you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some of the proposed solutions worked at the moment the question was made (March 2010) but today, August 2014, the solution of disabling empty inputs is just not working. The disabled fields are sended too in my Google Chrome. However, I tried removing the "name" attribute and it worked fine!

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[name], select[name]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()){
            $(this).removeAttr('name');
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:**
Ok, probably the reason because disabling fields doesn't worked to me is not that something changed since 2010. But still not working in my Google Chrome. I don't know, maybe is just in the linux version. Anyway, I think that removing the name attr is better since, despite what policy takes the browser about disabled fields, there is no way to send the parameters if the name attr is missing. Another advantage is that usually disabling fields implies some style changes, and is not nice to see a style change in the form a second before the form is  finally submited.
There is also a drawback, as Max Williams mentioned in the comments, since the remove name attr solution is not toggleable. Here is a way to avoid this problem:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('input[name], select[name]').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()){
            $(this).data('name', $(this).attr('name'));
            $(this).removeAttr('name');
        }
    });
});

function recoverNames(){
    $(this).find('input[name], select[name]').each(function(){
        if ($(this).data('name')){
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).data('name'));
        }
    });
}
```

However, I think this is not a very common case since we are submitting the form so it is assumed that there is no need to recover the missing name attrs.

Comment: I use chrome and disabling the inputs in a form means that they're not sent.  I don't think this has changed since 2010.  The problem with doing it via removing the name attribute is that it's not toggle-able, ie once you've removed the name you can't add it back, unless you saved it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem helped me figure out my situation, which is a bit different - so maybe someone else can benefit from it. Instead of directly submitting a form, I needed to prevent empty form elements from being collected into a serialized array which is ***then*** posted via AJAX.

In my case, I simply needed to loop through the form elements and disable all that were empty, and then collect the leftovers into an array like so:

```
// Loop through empty fields and disable them to prevent inclusion in array
$('#OptionB input, select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
        $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
    }
});

// Collect active fields into array to submit
var updateData = $('#OptionB input, select').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or serialize, clear empty key=value pairs with regex and call window.location:

```
$("#form").submit( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //convert form to query string, i.e. a=1&b=&c=, then cleanup with regex
    var q = $(this).serialize().replace(/&?[\w\-\d_]+=&|&?[\w\-\d_]+=$/gi,""),
    url = this.getAttribute('action')+ (q.length > 0 ? "?"+q : "");
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I always recommend is to do that on server side, so you are able to:

1. Validate the input data correctly
2. Set default values
3. Change input values if needed
4. Have a clean URL or a friendly URL such as "/quizzes/english/level-1/"

Otherwise you will have to deal with text input, select, radio etc...

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I do use server side validation too, but in this case what i wanted to achieve was a url where the only parameters in the search params were the none-empty ones.  This doesn't make any difference server side but it gives nicer urls.