# How do I remove a parameter with blank response from URL generated by the <form> tag?

Tags: html

I am writing a search box in HTML that takes the user input and append it to the URL as a parameter. The code of the form looks like this.

```html
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="id" id="idresponse">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will bring the user from `example.com/test.html` to `example.com/test.html?id=12345678` assuming they entered `12345678` at the text box.

However, if the user inputted nothing and clicked Submit, they will be brought to `example.com/test.html?id=`, which I don't want. How can I modify the code so that the form knows that a certain field is left blank and do not send the parameter with the URL? In this case, the desired URL would be `example.com/test.html`.

edit 20210405 2057 changed the id of the input from `idresposne` to `idresponse` to avoid confusion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove empty fields from my form in the querystring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926673/how-can-i-remove-empty-fields-from-my-form-in-the-querystring)

Comment: Also see other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417928/delete-empty-values-from-forms-params-before-submitting-it or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376217/how-to-not-pass-empty-input-fields-in-html-form

Comment: Hmm, the solution from [the question you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417928/delete-empty-values-from-forms-params-before-submitting-it) is working, but it still leaves a ? trailing behind. Is it possible to remove it? Other answers uses jQuery but I cannot make jQuery to work.

Comment: sorry should be [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376217/how-to-not-pass-empty-input-fields-in-html-form)

Answer (score 2):

The so-called URL parameters is the **querystring** of the URL.

The following code does not use jQuery, but achieves a similar effect. (written by RobG)

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="disableEmptyInputs(this)" action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="id" id="idresponse">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
function disableEmptyInputs(form) {
  var controls = form.elements;
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (controls[i].value == '') controls[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
<script>
```

This will remove all the parameters but the ? will still trail the URL. i.e. the URL will be `example.com/test.html?` instead. However, this does not matter because they both point to the same address.

Refer to these links (kindly provided by Progman) for other ways of doing this, including using jQuery.

- [Delete empty values from form's params before submitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417928/delete-empty-values-from-forms-params-before-submitting-it)
- [Delete empty values from form's params before submitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417928/delete-empty-values-from-forms-params-before-submitting-it)
- [How can I remove empty fields from my form in the querystring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926673/how-can-i-remove-empty-fields-from-my-form-in-the-querystring)

Thanks.